# KQL return Security Event ID's and their count by computer

Tags: kql

I can’t figure out how to write a KQL query that would basically list all the Security Events ID’s and their count for each single computer.

[This query returns all the Event ID per computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIC8D.png)
[This query returns the count by Computer, EventID and Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiSl8.png)

Could anyone provide some hints please?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

This is close to what I'd like to have:
[image: results]
However, is there a way to get something like this (basically, without any kung-fu within Excel):
[image: cool to have]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using the [`count()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/count-aggfunction), with both `Computer` and `EventId` as the aggregation keys:

```
SecurityEvent
| where Timestamp > ago(12h)
| summarize count() by Computer, EventId
```

or, based on my understanding of the later comment, you could try this:

```
SecurityEvent
| where Timestamp > ago(12h)
| summarize count() by Computer, EventId
| summarize count_by_event_id = make_bag(pack(tostring(EventId), count_)) by Computer
```

Comment: Thank you Yoni. That worked. Just wondering, is there a way to create a query that would basically output the computer name in the computer column just once? Right now, the computer name is written as many times as many events id have been seen for it. I could work on the data in Excel, but was wondering if it could be achieved "out of the box" with KQL. Marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Thank you and I apologize for replying just now. I’ve update my question, if you would be so kind to have a look once more, that would be awesome !